# How do I move only part of the items at a time?

Tags: stardew-valley

For example I now have 14 turnips. I want to keep 5 of them in my chest. How can I achieve it? It seems that I always move all of them whenever I click.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Right-clicking (or pressing <kbd>X</kbd> on a keyboard or Xbox controller or <kbd>□</kbd> on a PS4 controller) allows you to move or pick up single items from a stack. Holding <kbd>shift</kbd> while right-clicking moves/picks up half the items in a stack.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out right-clicking does it... Didn't figure it out before.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you are playing with a Xbox Controller, the X button has the same effect as right-clicking an item.